# React Native not connecting to Socket.io socket

Tags: sockets, react-native, websocket, socket.io

I'm building an app on react-native, and want to implement socket.io, however for some reason I am having trouble doing so.

Here is my server code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
const port = 3000;

io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("User has connected!");
});

server.listen(port, () => console.log("Server has started"));
```

And my React Native code (trimmed down):

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

export default class InstructorView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            visibleModal: null,
            modalTitle: "Test",
            course: {}
        }
    }

componentDidMount() {
    //Socket
    const socket = io("http://PC IP Address:3000");
    console.log("Component Did Mount"); 
}

render(){
    //code
}
```

Within the componentDidMount() method, "Component Did Mount" is outputting as desired,  however, neither log of "User has connected"  nor "Server has started" is printing to the console, and I'm unsure why, as I had followed a YouTube tutorial step-by-step. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Server.js**

```
var app = require("express")();
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
server.listen(5000);
io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("socket id" + socket.id);
});
```

**App.js**

```
import io from "socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js";//<----import--
var e;
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    e = this;
    this.socket = io("http://PC IPAddress:5000", { jsonp: false });
  }
}
```

Try to use this code, it works for me.

Comment: Hi Paras,

Thanks for your reply. I tried making the modifications you suggested, however it still is not working for some reason, is it possible it has to do with my folder structure? My server.js file is in another folder.

Comment: After playing around a little bit more, it seems as though it is working, however it printed out "User has connected!" after I ran both the the server and the react native app from different terminals.

Comment: You have to do that first you have to start your server in another terminal and after that run react application.